# swift modify generic property of struct

Tags: swift, generics, properties, dplyr

I have a struct that has a generic property with a type constraint to a custom protocol. This protocol is empty, its sole purpose is to ensure only elements of certain types can be stored in this generic variable:

```
protocol MyProtocol {}

struct TypeA: MyProtocol {
    someProperty: String
}

struct TypeB: MyProtocol {
    someOtherProperty: Int
}

var a = TypeA(someProperty: "text")
var b = TypeB(someOtherProperty: 5)

// The following is the actual struct in question:

struct Item {
    var something: Int
    var elementOfTypeAorB: MyProtocol
}

var firstItem = Item(something: 10, elementOfTypeAorB: a)
var secondItem = Item(something: 3, elementOfTypeAorB: b)
```

When I want access to the properties of my "base" structs TypeA or TypeB I have to cast them to their original Type:

```
print((secondItem.elementOfTypeAorB as! TypeB).someOtherProperty)  // 5
```

I now want a func that checks if the property is of TypeB and if so, alter the value, so the function body could read:

```
if type(of: secondItem.elementOfTypeAorB) == TypeB.self {
    (firstItem.elementOfTypeAorB as! TypeB).someOtherProperty+=5
}
```

But I get an error message: Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'Int'

If I change my TypeA and TypeB structs to be classes, I can do as this:

```
if type(of: secondItem.elementOfTypeAorB) == TypeB.self {
    var modify = (secondItem.elementOfTypeAorB as! TypeB)
    modify.someOtherProperty+=5
}
```

As classes are reference types, the original someOtherProperty of secondItem... will be altered, but even a.someOtherProperty is changed (the latter does not matter, though, as a and b here are only helper variables.

But if I want to stay in the domain of structs, the only way I found to mutate the properties of the generic elementOfTypeAorB is to downcast them to a new variable, change this variable and write back the whole variable to the higher-level struct, like:

```
secondItem.elementOfTypeAorB = modify
```

This works fine, but in my actual project the TypeA and TypeB structs hold not only one single property, so that every time I want to alter just one of them having to make a copy of the whole struct and then again replace the whole struct with this modified copy seems quite expensive to me.

So, is there another way to change the properties of generic structs I just didn't come across yet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform an optional cast:

```
if var elementA = elementOfTypeAorB as? TypeA {
    elementA.someProperty = ...
    elementOfTypeAorB = elementA
} else if var elementB = elementOfTypeAorB as? TypeB {
    elementB.someOtherProperty = ...
    elementOfTypeAorB = elementA
}
```

Also, instead of checking the type using `type(of: value) == Type`, you should use `value is Type`.

Alternatively, consider using an enum with associated values. It fits your use case much better, as protocols should be used to define an interface which can be used to interact with an instance.

```
enum AorB {
    case a(TypeA)
    case b(TypeB)
}
```

This allows you to restrict the type of your variable to TypeA and TypeB.

You can then use a `switch case` or `if case` statement to unwrap the value:

```
switch elementOfTypeAorB {
    case .a(var elementA):
        elementA.someProperty = ...
        elementOfTypeAorB = .a(elementA)
    case .b(var elementB):
        elementB.someOtherProperty = ...
        elementOfTypeAorB = .b(elementB)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will have look into the solution with enum instead of protocols, but the rest of the answer is basically: the only solution is to do as I wrote in my last 2 paragraphs: downcast a copy to a new var, change values there end rewrite to the original, right?